# Cannot run Xbap application on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, browser, xbap

I am downloading an WPF Xbap application from the follwing link:

http://ttpdownload.bl.uk/app_files/xbap/BrowserApp.xbap

which is opened in my Internet Explorer 11 but I got the following error:

> Application Download Error The application cannot be downloaded.Check
>   for network connectivity issues or contact the application publisher
>   for assistance.
>
> My error log is :
>
> PLATFORM VERSION INFO     Windows             : 6.3.9600.0 (Win32NT)  Common
>   Language Runtime  : 4.0.30319.33440   System.Deployment.dll       :
>   4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL   clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL   dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.33440 built by:
>   FX45W81RTMREL     dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384
>   (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
>
> SOURCES   Deployment url          :
>   file:///C:/Users/Musammil/AppData/Local/Temp/BrowserApp-3.xbap
>
> IDENTITIES    Deployment Identity     : BrowserApp.xbap, Version=1.1.131.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8bed49b226483885,
>   processorArchitecture=msil
>
> APPLICATION SUMMARY   * Online only application.  * Trust url parameter
>   is set. ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of
>   these errors are listed later in the log.     * An exception occurred
>   while downloading the manifest. Following failure messages were
>   detected:         + Downloading
>   file:///C:/Users/Musammil/AppData/Local/Temp/BrowserApp.exe.manifest
>   did not succeed.      + Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\Musammil\AppData\Local\Temp\BrowserApp.exe.manifest'.       +
>   Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\Musammil\AppData\Local\Temp\BrowserApp.exe.manifest'.       +
>   Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\Musammil\AppData\Local\Temp\BrowserApp.exe.manifest'.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY   No transaction error was
>   detected.
>
> WARNINGS  There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS     No phase information is available.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [11/25/2013 11:16:03 AM]
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown
>   subtype)
>         - Downloading file:///C:/Users/Musammil/AppData/Local/Temp/BrowserApp.exe.manifest
>   did not succeed.
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
>   subState)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri&
>   sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification,
>   DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest
>   deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri,
>   IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri&
>   appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindCore(Boolean
>   blocking, TempFile& tempDeploy, TempDirectory& tempAppDir, FileStream&
>   refTransaction, String& productName)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindAsyncWorker()
>         --- Inner Exception ---         System.Net.WebException
>         - Could not find file 'C:\Users\Musammil\AppData\Local\Temp\BrowserApp.exe.manifest'.
>         - Source: System
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>             at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)         --- Inner Exception ---         System.Net.WebException
>         - Could not find file 'C:\Users\Musammil\AppData\Local\Temp\BrowserApp.exe.manifest'.
>         - Source: System
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)          at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)       ---
>   Inner Exception ---       System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>         - Could not find file 'C:\Users\Musammil\AppData\Local\Temp\BrowserApp.exe.manifest'.
>         - Source: mscorlib
>         - Stack trace:          at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)          at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
>   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy,
>   Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)           at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)             at
>   System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length,
>   Boolean async)            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest
>   request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS   No transaction information is
>   available.

Why I can't run the xbap application whats the wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Internet Option --> Security Tab --> Custom level... --> and Enable the option **XAML browser applications**.

I think I don't need to say this but you need to make this change for every client you want to run your app. It was a security change [introduced in IE9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/09/internet-explorer-9-xbap-disabled-in-the-internet-zone.aspx) for Internet Zones.

I sucessfully run your app. It has some books in one shelve. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the BrowserApp.xbap to run there must be 2 other files located at the same site:

BrowserApp.exe.manifest

and

BrowserApp.exe

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but instead of allowing all sites to run XBAPs another approach might be to enable Enterprise Mode in IE11 for that specific site and hopefully that'll mean it's running in IE8 mode which in turn means XBAPs should be enabled in the Internet zone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of end users report this issue when connecting to an intranet application but got the error when the user tried to run the xbap file. Here's what I did to solve it for those users.

1. Close browsers
2. Delete temporary internet files in local appsdata folder
3. Set Internet explorer as default browser